Looking to optimize a batch query that is throwing a 'running too long' error
I have a batch process for Task assignments based on new and updated records. I have added date and formula-based filters in the query and am still running into the error. On any given day there should fewer than a thousand records that meet the criteria. New ones are updated on an ongoing basis, and the tasks may have a certain urgency depending on the ship date (referenced in the query). The goal is to take the current set of records, including those that already have tasks, and assign any new tasks in a round-robin fashion to the customer service team.
        query = 'SELECT Id, Name, ..., Data_Source__c, ' +
                '(Select Id, OwnerId from Tasks where Subject = \'<subject/>\') ' + 
             'FROM   CustomObject__c ' +
             'WHERE  CreatedDate > :aWeekAgo ' + 
             'AND    Is_Submitted__c = \'True\' ' +
             'AND    Modified_Today__c = true ' +
             'AND    Ship_Date__c > Today ' +
             'AND    Supplies_Needed_Before_Delivery__c = true';

I understand that the processing will take time, hence the batch, but I am having trouble identifying how to optimize the query.

I suggest to remove the subquery from start method and move the task retrieval inside of the execute method. Another option would be change the query to search by tasks instead of custom object with a semi-join. I vaguely recall nested queries causing issues and there is a previous answer from sfdcfox (which knows a lot more than me): https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154858/nested-soql-queries-and-batch-apex#154866

Thanks @JefersonChaves, that makes sense - there will be more records in the initial batch, but re-querying should be fine.  I'll let you know..

Thanks again @JefersonChaves (and sfdcfox, of course); simplifying that initial batch query let me focus on the actual processing where the real issues lived.  All good now! :D

@JefersonChaves - may I suggest that you should write up your comment as an answer to serve the community?
